# Getting the error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed" when doing notifyDataSetChanged for viewPager adapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager, illegalstateexception

I am calling notifyDataSetChanged() for view pager adapter from activity class inside onActivityResult(...) method. I am facing "Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
" error only in some devices. Below is the stack trace.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1515)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:638)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:621)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:139)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dataSetChanged(ViewPager.java:1003)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$PagerObserver.onChanged(ViewPager.java:2996)
   at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(PagerAdapter.java:279)
   at com.demo.activities.ActivityMain$1.run(ActivityMain.java:180)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6351)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:896)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:786)
```

The view pager contains only two Fragments(v4). I am getting the error in the line where I am doing notifyDataSetChanged in the below code.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 

    if (resultCode == 100) {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mViewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }}
```

Do I need to perform any check inside run method to examine whether activity still exists or not to avoid this exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you access the instance variable or context with Delay or in a callback you should check for its existence first.

**For Activity**

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(!isFinishing())
            mViewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, 1000);
```

**For fragment**

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(isAdded())
            mViewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, 1000);
```